# Why can't i generate this 10x10 2D array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to generate this 2D Array maze 10 by 10 with numbers 0-9 in each row for 10 rows, but I keep getting array out of bounds exception. I double checked my indexes and the loop format and everything looks standard.

```
public class MazeDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Maze maze = new Maze(10, 10);
        maze.generate();
    }
}

class Maze {
    int N, M;
    int[][] cell = new int[N][M];
    public Maze(int N, int M) {
        this.N = N;
        this.M = M;
    }

    public void generate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int j = 0; i < M; j++) {
                cell[i][j] = counter;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        display(cell, 10, 10);

    }

    public static void display(int a[][], int N, int M) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is going on here? Why am I getting the out of bounds exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `cell`, `N` and `M` are `0`. Change it to something like

```
int N, M;
int[][] cell;
public Maze(int N, int M) {
    this.N = N;
    this.M = M;
    this.cell = new int[N][M]; // <-- add this.
}
```

And in `generate`, this

```
for (int j = 0; i < M; j++) {
```

should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
```

Comment: @ Elliot two questions, why put the array in the constructor specified and secondly why have the syntax in that format? Thanks

Comment: @SkyZ When you say `int N, M;`, because `N` and `M` are primitive `int`s, they have the value `0`. If you don't put the initialization in the constructor, you get an array `[0][0]`.  As for the format of the syntax, it's covered by [JLS-15.10.1. Array Creation Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `generate` method in:

```
for (int j = 0; i < M; j++)
                ^
```

it should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
```